# Currency Conversion column in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I need to make a new column which converts currency in my list, like suppose,  if i submit a button it should convert dollars to INR IN Share Point 2013.

Can anyone help me out with this? I need step by step procedure as i am a beginner in sharepoint

Comment: How do you plan to get your conversion factors? Hard coded? From a web site? How update do they need to be? (the day the item was entered, or updated real time?)

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need to convert to just one other type of currency, or many, you can start with a Calculated Column in your list. For example, to convert from one type to another type, when you create your list:

1 - create one column of NUMBER type.  This is where the user enters in a number (for whatever currency you're converting FROM).  Then...

2 - create another column of CALCULATED type.  In the FORMULA field, enter in your equation based on your first column.  For example, you'd put something like:

=[USD] / 2

..or whatever the conversion equation is for the currency you're converting to.

You can choose it to come out as either currency or number, whichever works best for you.